# pypy5.1.1 errors installing packages

Tags: python, pypy

## Environment：

```
$cat /etc/issue
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.2 (Santiago)
Kernel \r on an \m

$pypy
Python 2.7.10 (b0a649e90b6642251fb4a765fe5b27a97b1319a9, May 26 2016, 05:22:09)
[PyPy 5.1.1 with GCC 4.8.5] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>>
```

## Issue

Some errors occurs When i install some python packages through remote calls. I am having trouble getting Pypy working.Thanks for your help.

```
Installing collected packages: pip, MarkupSafe, Jinja2, Pygments, backports.ssl-match-hostname, docutils, jsonschema, lxml, py, raven, six, singledispatch, certifi, backports-abc, tornado, coverage, requests, pymongo, redis, xmltodict, memory-profiler, futures, pycurl, PyCrypto, MySQL-python, sqlalchemy, thrift, suds-jurko, motor, gevent, setproctitle, gunicorn, protobuf, xxtea, PyYAML, argh, pathtools, watchdog, python-geohash, asyncetcd, shieldclient
  Found existing installation: pip 9.0.1
    Uninstalling pip-9.0.1:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-9.0.1
  Running setup.py install for MarkupSafe: started
    Running setup.py install for MarkupSafe: finished with status 'error'
    Complete output from command /home/admin/amap-aos-amapspypy/virtualenv/bin/pypy -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-ximZau/MarkupSafe/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-c5DXBc-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/admin/amap-aos-amapspypy/virtualenv/include/site/python2.7/MarkupSafe:
    debug: OperationError:
    debug:  operror-type: OSError
    debug:  operror-value: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

Comment: You should report it in pypy's bug tracker, where we'll ask you for more information in order to debug it.

Comment: Also, maybe we fixed the problem already.  Try a more recent version of pypy...

Comment: I installed the package successfully through  the local bash environment. But it was failed when installed through remote rpc called by platform.  
It was doubted  about the environmental variables. But  I am not sure which system variables is decided.